# get json data in function php

Tags: php, mysql, json, function

I am new in this json chapter.I have a file named mysql_conn.php .This file have a php function to call data from mysql database.So can anyone help me to create one json file to get data from mysql_conn.php.Below is my code

**mysql_conn.php**

```
function getWrkNoTest($wrkno){

    $conf = new BBAgentConf();
    $log = new KLogger($conf->get_BBLogPath().$conf->get_BBDateLogFormat(),  $conf->get_BBLogPriority() );
    $connection = MySQLConnection();

    $getWrkNoTest ="";
    $lArrayIndex = 0;

        $query = mysql_query("
                                SELECT 
                                    a.jobinfoid, 
                                    a.WRKNo, 
                                    a.cate, 
                                    a.det, 
                                    a.compclosed, 
                                    a.feedback, 
                                    a.infoID, 
                                    b.callerid, 
                                    b.customername 
                                FROM bb_jmsjobinfo a
                                LEFT JOIN bb_customer b 
                                    ON a.customerid = b.customerid
                                WHERE a.WRKNo = '$wrkno';"
        );

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $log->LogDebug("Query[".$query."]");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $getWrkNoTest = array("jobinfoid"=>$row['jobinfoid'],
                "WRKNo"=>$row['WRKNo'],
                "cate"=>$row['cate'],
                "det"=>$row['det'],
                "compclosed"=>$row['compclosed'],
                "feedback"=>$row['feedback'],
                "infoID"=>$row['customerid'],
                "customerid"=>$row['infoID'],
                "callerid"=>$row['callerid'],
            "customername"=>$row['customername']);

            $iList[$lArrayIndex] = $getWrkNoTest;
            $lArrayIndex = $lArrayIndex + 1;

        }
        $QueryResult = print_r($getWrkNoTest,true);
        $log->LogDebug("QueryResult[".$QueryResult."]");
        closeDB($connection);
        return $iList;
}
```

**json.php**

```
if ($_GET['action']=="getJsonjms"){
        $wrkno = $_GET["wrkno"];

        if($wrkno != ""){
            $jms = getWrkNoTest($wrkno);
            if(!empty($jms)){                
                echo json_encode($jms);
            }else{
                echo "No data.";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Please insert wrkno";
        }

}
```

I dont know how to solve this.Maybe use foreach or something else.Sorry for my bad english or bad explanation.I'm really new in this json things. Any help will appreciate.Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you trying to save the results of the mysql query into an actual json file (such as `results.json`)?

Comment: yes . I want create one json file to hold the data from the mysql_conn.php file .Thats all.

Comment: is that possible to create one json file to get data from php function in another file .But how ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want to convert the results you receive from your MySQL query into JSON and then store that data into a file?

If this is correct, you can build off of what you currently have in [`json.php`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). In this block here, you use `json_encode()`:

```
if(!empty($jms)){                
    echo json_encode($jms);
}
```

We can take this data and pass it to [`file_put_contents()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to put it into a file:

```
if (!empty($jms)) {
    $json = json_encode($jms);

    // write the file
    file_put_contents('results.json', $json);
}
```

If this is a script/page that's visited frequently, you'll want to make the filename (above as `results.json`) into something more dynamic, maybe based on the `$wrkno` or some other schema.